# How to format String with a pattern

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I want to format my string in my select statement but I cant seem to find the syntax for this pattern.

I have a column of card_num with 16 digits and i want to have a dash(-) after the first four digits.

Original card_num: 
1234567891234567

Desired output:
1234-567891234567

I think regex can do this but cant find elsewhere the right code for this pattern.

Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use substr() and concatenation (Oracle 12c): select the first 4 characters, then concatenate '-' and the rest of the string.

```
create table t
as
select '1234567891234567' card_num from dual;

select card_num
, substr(card_num, 1,4) || '-' || substr(card_num, 5, length(card_num) - 4) 
  formatted
from t;

SQL> select card_num
  2  , substr(card_num, 1,4) || '-' || substr(card_num, 5, length(card_num) - 4) 
  3    formatted
  4  from t;

CARD_NUM          FORMATTED          
1234567891234567  1234-567891234567
```

... the table is "overkill" for this example - but it may make it easier to experiment/adjust your query.

Comment: I just realized that substr is a lot way better for this example. It slipped my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  regexp_replace('1234567891234567', '(.{4})(.{12})', '\1-\2') as card_number
from dual;

CARD_NUMBER
-----------------
1234-567891234567
```

Comment: I have a feeling that @stefan 's soution would be more efficient - no?

Comment: @Vérace Maybe, I experienced that `substr` and similar functions performed better than `regexp` functions in simple string manipulation. But OP specifically mentioned regex.

Comment: True - plus one!

Comment: Substr slipped my mind. Im too focused on regex. My bad. I just realized it's more efficient. I already upvote your answer. Thanks anyways.